# Filter columns with regex in HANA

Tags: sql, hana

I recently started working with SAP HANA. So far I only used the graphical editor.

My problem is that I have to check the values inside a column (contract numbers) and either rewrite the value into a calculated column or assign the value "NA" to the calculated column if the contract number breaks the pattern `(\d{3}-\d{7}-\d{3})`.

In my research so far I found out that there is no supported function in the column engine to use regex. So I´d have to use SQL, is it possible to use that in a graphical calculation view?

Maybe someone can help.

Thanks!

Update: I figured out that I can use Table functions to access SQL functionality inside a graphical calculation view. Anyhow it seems a little overkill for my simple requirement.

Answer (score 2):

it´s actually possible to just use SQL in a calculated column. The editor shows an error even though that the query is fine and working.

I used this syntax in a calculated column:

```
CASE WHEN REPLACE_REGEXPR('[A-Z]\d{8}' IN "ZUONR" WITH 'Treffer' OCCURRENCE ALL) = 'Treffer' THEN "ZUONR" 
WHEN REPLACE_REGEXPR('\d{3}-\d{7}-\d{3}' IN "ZUONR" WITH 'WiederTreffer' OCCURRENCE ALL) = 'WiederTreffer' THEN "ZUONR"
ELSE 'NA' END
```